# I'm having trouble opening a Python file :(

Tags: python, file

I saved a file as DictionaryE.txt in a Modules folder I created within Python. Then I type:

```
fh = open("DictionaryE.txt")
```

I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#17>", line 1, in <module>
    fh = open("DictionaryE.txt")
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'DictionaryE.txt'
```

What am I doing wrong? Could someone please describe a specific, detailed step-by-step instruction on what to do? Thanks.

Comment: Why would it not be 'fh = open("DictionaryE.txt")'?

Comment: you're right, fixed that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As other answers suggested, you need to specify the file's path, not just the name.

For example, if you know the file is in `C:\Blah\Modules`, use

```
fh = open('c:/Blah/Modules/DictionaryE.txt')
```

Note that I've turned the slashes "the right way up" (Unix-style;-) rather than "the Windows way".  That's optional, but Python (and actually the underlying C runtime library) are perfectly happy with it, *and* it saves you trouble on many occasions (since `\`, in Python string literals just as in C ones, is an "escape marker", once in a while, if you use it, the string value you've actually entered is *not* the one you think -- with '/' instead, zero problems).

Comment: +1 I didn't know this. All the while I was using `r"C:\path\to\file.txt"`

Answer (score 1):

Use the full path to the file? You are trying to open the file in the current working directory.

Comment: And how do I figure out the full path to the file?

Comment: The answer below that suggests using the path to the current file is probably a good way.

Answer (score 0):

probably something like:

```
import os
dict_file = open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'Modules', 'DictionaryE.txt'))
```

It's hard to know without knowing your project structure and the context of your code. Fwiw, when you just "open" a file, it will be looking in whatever directory you're running the python program in, and `__file__`is the full path to ... the python file.

Answer (score 0):

To complement Alex's answer, you can be more specific and explicit with what you want to do with `DictionaryE.txt`. The basics:

**READ (this is default):**

```
fh = open("C:/path/to/DictionaryE.txt", "r")
```

**WRITE:**

```
fh = open("C:/path/to/DictionaryE.txt", "w")
```

**APPEND:**

```
fh = open("C:/path/to/DictionaryE.txt", "a")
```

More info can be found here: [Built-in Functions - `open()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open)